# How to calculate the amount of sodium sulfate needed to lower the silver ion concentration of a saturated silver sulfate solution?

Tags: equilibrium, solubility, concentration, precipitation

> How many moles of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ we have to add into a saturated $\pu{0.5 L}$ solution of $\ce{Ag2SO4}$ so that the concentration of $\ce{Ag}$ is $\pu{4.0 \times 10^-3 M}$? ($K_\mathrm{sp} = 1.4 \times 10^{-5}$)

- I found out first $\ce{[SO4^2-]}$ in a normal saturated solution: 
  \begin{align}
  K_\mathrm{sp} &= [\ce{Ag+}]^2[\ce{SO4^2-}],\\
  1.4 \times 10^{-5} &= 4s^3,\\
  s &= 0.015
  \end{align} 
  So we have $\pu{0.015 M}$ of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ in this solution.
- Then, I find out $\ce{[SO4^2-]}$ needed for a saturated solution of $\ce{Ag2SO4}$ but with $[\ce{Ag}] = \pu{4.0 \times 10^-3 M}$:
  \begin{align}
  1.4 \times 10^{-5} &= (4.0 \times 10^{-3})^2 \times [\ce{SO4^2-}],\\
  [\ce{SO4^2-}] &= 0.875
  \end{align}
  So we need $\pu{0.875 M}$ of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ in such saturated solution.
- So the difference of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ is $\pu{0.875 M} - \pu{0.015 M} = \pu{0.86 M}$. So we need to add $\pu{0.86 M}$ of $\ce{SO4^2-}$, that is $\pu{0.43 mol}$ of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ($\pu{0.86 M} \times \pu{0.5 L} = \pu{0.43 mol}$).
- Eventually, we obtained we need to add $\pu{0.43 mol}$ of $\ce{Na2SO4}$.

The above are my calculations, can anyone tell me if my steps can be justified?

Comment: Why divide 0.86 moles by 2? It is $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ that is needed in the solution, not $\ce{Na+}$.

Comment: Oh, I just added a note to that, and I changed all mol/L to M so it might be more visible. It is 0.86 mol/L, so I multiply it by 0.5 L in order to obtain the mole needed which is 0.43 mol

Comment: Dah... I didn't read the problem correctly. Dividing by 2 was correct.

Comment: Haha. No worries, it happens

Comment: In the given data, $\ce{K_s_p}$ = $\ce{1.4 x 10^{-5}}$. But two lines later, you write another value for the same constant. You write that $\ce{K_s_p}$ = $\ce{4.0 x 10^{-3}}$. Why ? All the following calculations are wrong.

Comment: @Maurice sorry, it might be a typo. I calculated all the data using the right number. Thank you for noting that! I have just changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are true to a certain extend. However, you neglected the amount of $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions precipitated as $\ce{Ag2SO4}$. And also, since we are calculating in the means of concentration terms, we have to assume that addition of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ solid did not change the original $\pu{0.5 L}$-volume.

You calculated correctly the concentration of $\ce{[SO4^2-]}$ ions ($s$) in the original saturated solution, which is equal to the solubility of $\ce{Ag2SO4}$ ($s$):

$$K_\mathrm{sp} = [\ce{Ag+}]^2[\ce{SO4^2-}]= (2s)^2 \times s= 4s^3= 1.4 \times 10^{-5} $$
$$\therefore \; s = \left(\frac{1.4 \times 10^{-5}}{4}\right)^\frac{1}{3} = 1.52 \times 10^{-2}$$

You also calculated correctly the concentration of $\ce{[SO4^2-]}$ ions in the solution after certain amount of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ solid was added (suppose it is $m$ mols) to make  the concentration of $\ce{Ag+}$ ions is equal to $\pu{4.0 \times 10^{-3} M}$:

$$K_\mathrm{sp} = [\ce{Ag+}]^2[\ce{SO4^2-}]= (4.0 \times 10^{-3})^2 \times [\ce{SO4^2-}] = 1.4 \times 10^{-5}$$
$$\therefore \; [\ce{SO4^2-}] = \left(\frac{1.4 \times 10^{-5}}{16.0 \times 10^{-6}}\right) = \left(\frac{1.4}{1.6}\right) = \pu{0.875 M}$$

Thus, you have $\pu{0.875 M}$ of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ ions in this solution. However, note that some of $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions would be precipitated as solid $\ce{Ag2SO4}$ when you keep adding $\ce{Na2SO4}$ solid (*vide supra*) in order to maintain the equilibrium (Le Chatelier's principle). This amount is equal to the half of $[\ce{Ag+}]$ ions precipitated with it:

$$\therefore \; [\ce{SO4^2-}]_{ppt} = \frac{1}{2}\left(2 \times 1.52 \times 10^{-2} - 4.0 \times 10^{-3} \right)= \pu{1.32 \times 10^{-2} M}$$

Suppose you add $m$ amount (in moles) of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ to the original solution. which already had $\pu{1.52 \times 10^{-2} M}$ of $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions. Thus, $[\ce{SO4^{2-}}]$ remain in the solution:

$$[\ce{SO4^{2-}}]_{remain} = \pu{0.875 M} = m + 1.52 \times 10^{-2} - 1.32 \times 10^{-2} $$

$$\therefore \; m = 0.875 - 0.20 \times 10^{-2} \approx \pu{0.873 M}$$

Thus, you need to add $\pu{0.873 mol/L}\times \pu{0.5 L} \approx \pu{0.437 mol}$ of $\ce{Na2SO4}$ to the original solution.